# Mounting QNAP folder via NFS: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs

I'm sure this question has been asked before in different ways, but my difference is that everything was working beautifully for me before upgrading my QNAP to the QTS 4.5.5.715 firmware. I'm not getting any help from the QNAP folks, so I thought I'd try my luck here.

- I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.
- Both the QNAP TS-453D and the Ubuntu desktop are hardwired to the router.
- nfs-common is installed on Ubuntu

On QNAP, I had granted "Access right" to the folder at issue, read/ write permission and "Squash no users."

To mount the QNAP, I would simply go to terminal and type:

mount -t nfs xxx.xxx.x.xxx:/FOLDER_ON_QNAP /home/username/FOLDER_ON_QNAP

Historically, this would mount the folder to my Ubuntu desktop via NFS seamlessly. It worked well. I never adjusted fstab or etc as whenever I needed to mount the QNAP, I just typed the above line into terminal, and like magic, it worked.

No, I'm getting the infamous:

mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting xxx.xxx.x.xxx:/FOLDER_ON_QNAP

...issue. Any idea as to how to fix this? I felt like my setup was relatively simple. For what it's worth, I can still access the folder over the network via AFP or SMB, but let's face it, neither is as good as nfs.

Many thanks.

Comment: Generally when I’ve run into this it’s because of user permissions; either mounting a share with an admin-level QNap account, or a desync’d user/pass between the two devices 

Comment: @matigo you're on to something -- thank you. I spent ages wrestling with permissions. When in the "NFS Host Access" on the QNAP, I set the allowed IP address simply to a single wildcard "*" it works perfectly. Obviously I don't want to do that, but at least I have a lead -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a networking issue, resolved by resetting my router and smart switch back to their factory defaults and setting up the network again from scratch.

Somehow, the local IP addresses of my desktop and QNAP (and Sonos and switch) went a bit haywire. How that happened, I don't know, but now everything is back to working right as rain again.